# how to add command line parameters when running java code in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

How can I add command line parameters to the JVM in Eclipse? For example, let's say I want to explicitly add -cp argument when running the JVM, is it possible? (I am giving it as an example, I realize I can add an external Jar to the project settings to get an additional classpath.)

The argument I want to add is `-agentlib:Shark` (on Mac OSx for running a profiler).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can specify vm arguments when creating a "Run Configuration" in Eclipse. Right-click on your project > Run Configuration > Java Application > Arguments tab.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How can I add - noVerify argument in external tomcat?

Answer (score 1):

Run --> Run Configurations --> Arguments

Answer (score 1):

In the Run menu, there is an entry "Run Configurations", which allows you to configure everything about the spawned JVM. It has a tab to set the classpath, and another called "Arguments" where you can set JVM parameters.