# Pass argument to a file java in eclipse

Tags: java, readfile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to add command line parameters when running java code in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8319939/how-to-add-command-line-parameters-when-running-java-code-in-eclipse)

When i run my program on tux and do a make run my program executes perfectly, the command in the make file is :

```
STS_ARGS = attributes.txt ts

run:
    java -ea -cp $(STS_CP) STS $(STS_ARGS)
```

and now when i try to run the file in eclipse

```
Input in = new Input("Attributes.txt ");
```

how do i pass "ts" as an argument in eclipse ?

Answer (score 1):

Run Configurations -> Arguments - Program Arguments

Then enter the arguments to your program there.